# Moving Clustered Index to new filegroup results in excessive filegrowth

Tags: sql-server-2008, clustered-index, filegroups, compression

I've Moved the clustered index on large tables to new filegroups to defrag, compress, and to recover space more easily from the original "primary" filegroup.

**Problem:**

A 315GB compressed Clustered Index (page compression) resulted in a filegroup that expanded to over 650GB.  (Uncompressed, this table is north of 2TB.)  The free space is not limited to the end of the file, so it cannot be truncated - to shrink this file will be slow and likely result in increased fragmentation.

Let me know if you know how I can create this index without the excessive growth.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've found my own answer to this question.  When setting SORT_IN_TEMPDB on, the filegroup no longer expands unpredictably, and a shrink with truncate only is successful in recovering space which is all trailing space.  If trying this, note that this could result in additional space requirements for TempDB.

Comment: `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` causes the temporary mapping index of your presumed online operation to be created in tempdb.